# Partial View not loading once deployed

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a MVC 5 web site for Intranet use.  On one page there is a Partial View that displays some details of whatever item is selected in a Drop Down List.  This all works locally in Development.  However, once I deploy the site to our Internal Web Server it no longer does.  Everything else still does, Create, Edit, Delete, Details, Index, and a different Partial that loads on the Index page.

This Partial, which loads on the Create page using AJAX and is located in the same folder as `Create.cshtml`, does not.

Thoughts? I'm not even sure where to look first here...

This is on my Create page and is what loads the Partial, again this works great in local Dev.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ProductionOrder").change(function () {
            var po = $("#ProductionOrder").val().toString();
            $.get('/wetWashRequests/GetDetails?WONumber=' + po, function (data) {
                $('#ProductionOrderDetails').html(data);
                $('#ProductionOrderDetails').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

If I manually enter the URL displayed in that AJAX into a browser with a valid `WONumber` it returns the correct data.

This is the Method being called in the Controller:

```
public PartialViewResult GetDetails(string WONumber)
    {            
        var details = db.vwProductionOrderLookups.Where(x => x.No_ == WONumber).SingleOrDefault();
        return PartialView("_ProductionOrderDetails", details);
    }
```

---

EDIT

So, it seems to be related to the URL path.  If I change it, in the AJAX call to `ServerName/WetWashRequest/WetWashRequests/GetDetails` then it works.  I'm, guessing, that I deployed it wrong and I should need that extra `WetWashRequest` in the front....

Comment: do you get any messages in the console?

Comment: You're sure the `GetDetails(string WONumber)`method is returning a valid partial view? Have you alerted within the `$.get`'s success function to verify it's being called?

Comment: @Jonesy Console on the Web Server?  I'd have to look into how to do that.  Small shop here with many hats, some I've never worn before... :)

Comment: @GarySchreiner On production I can't be sure though I am 100% positive the same code works when physically ran from my machine versus the Web Server.

Comment: Look int othe dev tools on your browser and find the console.  It'll tell you what's going on.  I'm 99% sure it's building the wrong URL on your prod server

Comment: Sure, I'll do that, and DUH! I did know about that Console.  Sorry, difference between knowing a tool exists and what to use it for I guess.

Comment: glad you figured it out

Comment: @RefractedPaladin In my haste to read  it, I skipped over the part where you said it worked on dev and issue was on production, glad you were able to fix it.

Comment: @GarySchreiner No Worries, thanks for taking the time to read it.

Comment: Is this still not working correctly? or were you able to fix it all?

Comment: It is and it isn't.  Now, when I want to deploy I need to go in and and the Web Site Name to that AJAX call but when I want to run it on my system I need to get rid of it.  Seems like there is a better way....

Comment: I'm getting the Same problem how to give the Path for partial view?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, this is caused by how you have your development and production environments in different folders. The biggest problem will be your use of the relative (using / first), or absolute (including the server name in the front). Depending on your environment, make sure that the /wetWashRequests folder or API is on the top level, because that's what the Web Clients are looking for.